# Error after executing selenium with Chrome

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to execute Selenium with Chrome on Ubuntu 16.04 and what I do is:

```
Xvfb :10 -screen 0 1366x768x24 -ac &
google-chrome --remote-debugging-port=92222
```

When I execute the previous command I got this error:

```
 vagrant@smart:~$ [2207:2332:1118/135124.679982:ERROR:bus.cc(394)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")

 DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9222/devtools/browser/39519bf4-dad5-4557-86d7-29bde71ee025

 (google-chrome:2207): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Unable to get session bus: Unknown or unsupported transport 'disabled' for address 'disabled:'

 [2207:2207:1118/135124.939100:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(980)] Lost UI shared context.

 [1:8:1118/135125.063874:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(100)] ContextResult::kFatalFailure: Shared memory region is not valid
```

I run the selenium command:

```
  java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.5.jar
```

And when I try to create a session manually through the url I got what I show in picture.

[image]

I'm trying to work with some test with codecpetion and yii2 but initially I can't because of that. I'm using the lastest version of all components and I was working perfectly until today. As well I have chromedriver. What is happening?. I am running in a vagrant box and I'm trying to test my application with codeception and I have tried to reinstall selenium and chrome and I got nothing, Thanks so much.

Comment: Please [edit the question](/posts/53361258/edit) to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53361258/edit).

Comment: @DebanjanB, I did it and I just summarize all questions in just 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of a conflict between chromedriver, selenium and chrome. Downgrading chrome, it's solved